# How to make Person/Group and Look-up column values non-clickable in SharePoint 2013 list views

Tags: 2013, list-view, lookup-column, xslt-list-view-web-part, person

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. For a SharePoint 2013 XSL List View Web Part, I need for the person/group column value, as well as look-up column value to be non-clickable. I have seen multiple posts about how to do this in a NewForm or EditForm. But, I need it for list views.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of doing this (for all three forms) is to modify how the field itself is displayed.

That is, go to list settings -> select your "Person or Group" field to open its edit field page. Now there should be a drop-down at the very bottom saying something like "Specify which information to display", and there you will get options like "Email", "Name", "Name with presence" etc. Choose any one that suits you, and all the forms will behave accordingly. (If you choose "Name" it won't have a link, but there will be a few others too.)

Comment: I was hoping to be able use the Name with Presence, and to be able to make the name portion unclickable. I like being able to provide the presence indicator and the information it provides, just don't want anyone to be able to click the name and be taken to the mysite profile like it currently does.

Comment: Yeah - the specified desire is to display Name with Presence, but that Name wouldn't be clickable.